Trouble Setting Access Point 2.4GHz Orange Pi Zero 2
I'm setting up a WiFi Access Point using bridge mode. I successfully configured the bridge mode and it's working. Then, I managed to set up the WiFi Access Point for 5GHz as well. But why did I fail when setting it up for 2.4 GHz?
Trouble:

Visible after restart, then after 1-2 minuter, WiFi AP not visible
After restart, i cant access my orange pi with ssh or VNC, but can access with HDMI

This my configuration:
sudo nano /etc/hostapd.conf

Script:
#
# orangepi hostapd configuration example
#
# nl80211 mode
#

ssid=HIBOBGATEWAY
interface=wlan0
hw_mode=g
channel=6  # Set to a common 2.4GHz channel (1-13)
bridge=br0
driver=nl80211

logger_syslog=0
logger_syslog_level=0
wmm_enabled=1
wpa=2
preamble=1

wpa_psk=66eb31d2b48d19ba216f2e50c6831ee11be98e2fa3a8075e30b866f4a5ccda27
wpa_passphrase=6666666666
wpa_key_mgmt=WPA-PSK
wpa_pairwise=TKIP
rsn_pairwise=CCMP
auth_algs=1
macaddr_acl=0

### IEEE 802.11n
ieee80211n=1
ht_capab=[SHORT-GI-20][SHORT-GI-40][HT40+]
country_code=ID
ieee80211d=1
### IEEE 802.11n

### IEEE 802.11a
#hw_mode=a
### IEEE 802.11a

### IEEE 802.11ac
#ieee80211ac=1
#vht_capab=[MAX-MPDU-11454][SHORT-GI-80][TX-STBC-2BY1][RX-STBC-1][MAX-A-MPDU-LEN-EXP3]
#vht_oper_chwidth=1
#vht_oper_centr_freq_seg0_idx=42
### IEEE 802.11ac

# controlling enabled
ctrl_interface=/var/run/hostapd
ctrl_interface_group=0

For bridge setting:
sudo nano /etc/network/interfaces

Script
source /etc/network/interfaces.d/*
# Network is managed by Network manager
auto lo
iface lo inet loopback

auto eth0
allow-hotplug eth0
iface eth0 inet manual

auto wlan0
allow-hotplug wlan0
iface wlan0 inet manual
#wireless power off

auto br0
iface br0 inet static
address 192.168.6.57
netmask 255.255.255.0
gateway 192.168.6.254
bridge_ports eth0 wlan0
bridge_fd 0
bridge_stp off
Copy code

Can you help me?
Linux Kernel: Linux 4.9.170-sun50iw9
Distro: UBUNTU Bionic
Hardware: Orange-Pi Zero 2

Probably more suitable on superuser.com than here…

Please refer https://askubuntu.com/help/on-topic, Ubuntu and official flavors of Ubuntu are on-topic on this site. The on-topic link provides alternate SE sites for non-Ubuntu OSes.

Your details do not show you're using a Ubuntu system, at most a Ubuntu based system that includes non-Ubuntu kernel & other features. Ubuntu releases before 20.04 (bionic is 18.04) are also not in standard support  and thus off-topic here anyway now, as standard support for bionic ended last year.  FYI:  The oldest supported kernel of Ubuntu on-topic here is 5.4, with 4.19 not used by Ubuntu at all as that was a Debian kernel.

FYI:   The 4.19 kernel from Debian has already had it's EOL warnings out (https://www.debian.org/News/2024/20240615) so be aware of how old your software stack is... the Ubuntu components reached EOSS last year, as too is your Debian kernel now.  If security matters to you, it maybe safer offline.

@jcaron I'm sorry, someone migrate my question from IoT to here

@guiverc I'm sorry, someone migrate my question from IoT to here
